# How to mix styling in :after { content:

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to make a  element that will add [*sic*] after an incorrectly quoted word.

Using SCSS, here is what I have so far:

```
span {
    &.sic {
        &:after {
            content: "[""]"
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to keep the brackets how they are and add "sic" in italics between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can think of if you really want to have regular brackets and the `sic` to be italic is defining the `content` with your brackets along with italic characters like , so something like:

```
span {
  &.sic {
    &:after {
        content: "[]";
    }
  }
}
```

But I think it would be better with the unicode characters like:

```
content: "\005B\1D460\1D456\1D450\005D";
```

```css
span:after {
    content: "\005B\1D460\1D456\1D450\005D";
}
```

```html
<span>some text</span>
```

Otherwise you'd have to go with all italics:

```
&:after {
    content: "[sic]";
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Or no italics:

```
&:after {
    content: "[sic]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DarkAjax! Unicode is the simplest way to go. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use border and gradient to create the brackets and you can make only the text italic or change any other property without affecting the brackets:

```css
p:after {
  content:"Sic";
  font-style:italic;
  color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  padding:0 2px;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(#000 0,#000 1px,transparent 1px),
  linear-gradient(#000 0,#000 1px,transparent 1px),
  linear-gradient(to top,#000 0,#000 1px,transparent 1px),
  linear-gradient(to top,#000 0,#000 1px,transparent 1px)  ;
  background-position:0 0, 100% 0;
  background-size:3px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

**UPDATE**

Another version with less gradient and less code:

```css
p:after {
  content:"Sic";
  font-style:italic;
  color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  padding:0 2px;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
  --g:linear-gradient(#000 0,#000 1px,transparent 1px,transparent calc(100% - 1px),#000 calc(100% - 1px));
  background: var(--g) left,var(--g) right;
  background-size:3px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

You can also consider more CSS variable to easily adjust the needed values:

```css
:root {
  --b:1px;
  --c:#000;
}

p:after {
  content:"Sic";
  font-style:italic;
  color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  padding:0 2px;
  border-right:var(--b) solid var(--c);
  border-left:var(--b) solid var(--c);
  --g:linear-gradient(var(--c) 0,var(--c) var(--b),transparent var(--b),transparent calc(100% - var(--b)),var(--c) calc(100% - var(--b)));
  background: var(--g) left,var(--g) right;
  background-size:3px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p style="--b:2px;--c:blue">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p style="--b:3px;--c:purple">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use quotation marks like that in just about any code language, css is no exception. You need to use a single quote and double quote respectively.

```
span {
    &.sic {
        &:after {
            content: '["sic"]'
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you're wanting just the word

```
span {
    &.sic {
        &:after {
            content: "sic"
        }
    }
}
```